# updating list item of a file using CSOM

Tags: client-object-model, updatelistitems, copy-item

I am using following code to copy a file from a Document Library to another. The file is copied and is there, but the fields will not be updated.

```
fileInfo = File.OpenBinaryDirect(srcClntCntxt, fileServerRelativeUrl);

using (ClientContext clntCntxt = ContextHelper.DestinationClientContex())
{
   Web web = clntCntxt.Web;
   clntCntxt.Load(web);
   clntCntxt.ExecuteQuery();

   string nLocation = web.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/') + "/destLib/fileName";

    File.SaveBinaryDirect(clntCntxt, nLocation, fileInfo.Stream, true);
    File newFile = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(nLocation);
    ListItem newFileItem = newFile.ListItemAllFields;
    clntCntxt.Load(newFile);
    clntCntxt.Load(newFileItem);
    clntCntxt.ExecuteQuery();

    newFile.CheckOut();
    newFileItem["MyComments"] = "test test"; //this is a multi line text 
    newFileItem.Update();
    newFile.CheckIn(string.Empty, CheckinType.OverwriteCheckIn);
    clntCntxt.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Nadeem, where exactly do I need to add it. When I add it before checkOut it casts this: You can only publish, unpublish  documents in a minor version enabled list

Comment: No, It didn't work

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
clntCntxt.Load(newFile);
clntCntxt.ExecuteQuery();

//check out to make sure not to create multiple versions
newFile.CheckOut();

ListItem newFileItem = newFile.ListItemAllFields;
newFileItem["MyComments"] = "test";
newFileItem.Update();

// use OverwriteCheckIn type to make sure not to create multiple versions 
newFile.CheckIn(string.Empty, CheckinType.OverwriteCheckIn);
```

Comment: Amal, I can not see any difference between your code and mine

Comment: I reversed Update and CheckIn

Comment: I am sorry about my mistake, I have already tested it, Now I have updated the question.

Comment: Can you check "MyComments" is the correct internal name of the field?

Comment: Yes it is the Internal Name of the field

Comment: Your answer was right. I will mark it as answer tomorrow.

Comment: How can I update the entire file after checking out? and not just MyComments?